# inject an email into another user's procmail

Tags: email, procmail

I use a second account to archive mailing lists and make my business email remotely available via pop3.  I have it working now with a procmail rule that copies to the second email address.
Doing it this way causes the email to be reprocessed by virus, spam, and other filters that have already passed the message.  I'm looking for a way to copy the message to a second procmail running with the second account's credentials and procmail config files.

Answer (score 0):

You could coordinate the two accounts by adding a secret tag before forwarding to the other account.  The presence of this flag would cause virus etc checks to be bypassed.  Obviously, anybody who knows the secret tag will be able to bypass security checks, though!

```
# Primary account forwards to pop3@example.com
:0c
| formail -I"X-Secret: xyzzy" | sendmail -oi pop3@example.com
```

Then for the secondary account, right at the top of the `.procmailrc`,

```
# Bypass virus checking if X-Secret is there
:0
* ^X-Secret: xyzzy$
$DEFAULT
```

This is a proof of concept and not a set-up I particularly recommend.  In any event, doing the virus and spam checking at a higher level than individual users' `.procmailrc` files is probably a better overall approach.